# Delete all rows in a file that fit between certain headers?

Tags: r

I would like to delete all of the rows that sit between certain headers in this example text file.

```
    fileConn <- file("sample.txt")
    one <- "*Keyword"
    two <- "*Node"
    three <- "$ Node,X,Y,Z"
    four <- "1,639982.78040607,4733827.5104821,0"
    five <- "2,639757.59709573,4733830.43494066,0"
    six <- "3,639738.81268144,4733834.3619618,0"
    seven <- "*End"
    writeLines (c(one, two, three, four, five, six, seven), fileConn)
    close(fileConn)

    sample <- readLines("sample.txt")
```

What I am looking to do is delete all of the rows/lines between `"*Node"` and `"*End"`. Since I am dealing with files with different lengths of rows between these headers, the deletion method needs to be based on headers only. I have no idea how to do this since I've only deleted rows in dataframes referenced by row numbers previously. Any clues?

Expected output is:

```
    *Keyword
    *Node
    *End
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. `$ Node,X,Y,Z` can also be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

`readLines` returns a vector, not a data frame, so we can create the sample input more simply:

```
sample = c("*Keyword",
"*Node",
"$ Node,X,Y,Z",
"1,639982.78040607,4733827.5104821,0",
"2,639757.59709573,4733830.43494066,0",
"3,639738.81268144,4733834.3619618,0",
"*End")
```

Find the starting and ending headers, and remove the elements in between with negative indexing:

```
node = which(sample == "*Node")
end = which(sample == "*End")

result = sample[-seq(from = node + 1, to = end - 1)]
result
# [1] "*Keyword" "*Node"    "*End"
```

This assumes there is a single `*Node` and a single `*End` line. It also assumes that there is at least one line to delete. You may want to create a more robust solution with some handling for those special cases, e.g.,

```
delete_between = function(input, start, end) {
  start_index = which(sample == start)
  end_index = which(sample == end) 
  if (length(start_index) == 0 | length(end_index) == 0) {
    warning("No start or end found, returning input as-is")
    return(input)
  }
  if (length(start_index) > 1 | length(end_index) > 1) {
    stop("Multiple starts or ends found.")
  } 
  if (start_index == end_index - 1) {
    return(input)
  }
  return(input[-seq(from = start_index + 1, to = end_index - 1)])
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!